# Search field making duplicate div classes in IE8 and IE9

Tags: html, css, forms, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

A website I'm currently working on is acting weird in IE8 and IE9. The problem is with my search form at the top of the page. It is creating a double class where it shouldn't (I have one div 'search' class and thats it), and it's forcing my facebook button into another line below within the duplicated div.

Please visit http://tbuas.firedogbeta.com in IE8 or IE9, and look at the search box at the top. I'm really stumped on this one.

Answer (score 1):

You have `<a/>` instead of `</a>` at this line:

```
<div class="logo"><a href="/index.php"><img src="/themes/TBUAS/images/tbuas-logo.png" alt="TBUAS" /><a/></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an opening tag on your `<a>` element.  Right after the `<div class="search">` tag, put a `<a>` tag.

Firefox automatically inserts this for you, but IE obviously doesn't quite know where to put it, so it ignores the ending tag completely.  The ending tag is already there, though, so everything should be good after this fix.

Answer (score 0):

in firefox, if missing close tag, it auto make close tag, so we don't see any problem.
But in IE, it doesn't.